# Convert textbox text to int - Error even after TryParse()

Tags: c#, type-conversion, tryparse

What should (hopefully) be a simple problem...

I have a function called updateChart(), where the program takes a value input from a textbox (txtBP), and tries to convert it into an integer to be stored in a local variable (latestReading) and used as a graph coordinate.

I originally tried to do this like this:

```
int latestReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtBP.Text);
```

This caused a run-time error informing me that "Input string was not in the correct format". After some research I have learned that to convert text from a textbox to an int, you should use the TryParse method. I tried this method out as such:

```
int x = 0;
int latestReading = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(txtBP.Text, out x))
{
    latestReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtBP.Text);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Reading!");
}
```

I was sure this would work, but when it came to testing, even entering the the value 1 into the textbox myself caused it to jump to the 'else' part of the statement. I have read around on stack overflow but can't find a similar situation.

Comment: can you debug each line of the code, and check what's the value of txtBP.Text when it passed your condition?

Comment: Did you debug your code and see your `txtBP.Text` is _really_ `1`?

Comment: Actually you don't need to use `Convert.ToInt32(txtBP.Text)` with `TryParse`. If it succeeded you can use `x` directly. Note that you should use `txtBP.Text.Trim()` if it can contain leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: Try to add `MessageBox.Show(txtBP.Text);` before `if (Int32.TryParse(txtBP.Text, out x))`

Comment: try to put a breakpoint on tryparse and inspect what is the actual value of txBP.Text, most certainly it is not a valid int

Comment: "I have learned that to convert text from a textbox to an int, you should use the `TryParse` method." The difference between `Parse` and `TryParse` is that `TryParse` returns `false` for inputs that cause `Parse` to throw an exception, so switching from `Parse` to `TryParse` would silence the error, but it would not help parsing the value.

Comment: Check with this site https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx. it might help you

Comment: Change in your code `latestReading = Convert.ToInt32(txtBP.Text);` to `latestReading = x;`. (I think this is also what Tim meant).

Comment: I've just assigned the value in txtBP to a local variable called BPstring and debugged each line of the code. Even once the variable has been initialised, the debugger comes back with a value of "" for BPstring. This would seem like the value entered into the textbox is not being registered at all.. anybody any ideas?

Comment: This might sound stupid, but are you sure the textbox you're editing is really `txtBP`? And if so, when/how do you assign `BPstring = txtBP`?

Comment: Yes it is txtBP, don't worry I made sure to check! I didn't use `BPstring = txtBP.Text` originally, I just declared it at the top of the updateChart function so that there was a variable I could check in the debugger. @Corak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to let everyone know, I got the thing working.

Calling the updateChart() function on the button click seemed to be throwing it off, by calling it inside a function that was already called on the button click, it seems to be able to access the data from the textbox. Still not entirely sure how this happens but no complaining.

Thank you to you all for your help!

Mark